# An Array of Pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop

**CODE UPDATED BASED ON ANSWERS BELOW AND WARNINGS/ISSUES REFLECTED**

I am trying to code an array of pointers in C. A loop sets the values and another loop retrieves them - fairly straight forward. Here's how I am trying to set those values:

```
static int  *toInvert[8];
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
              int *intrplated = //Function call that returns int*
              toInvert[i] = intrplated;
              //printf("OL Value = %d\n\n\n\n\n",oLoop);
}
```

And to retrieve the values, here's the code without the loop, i.e., retrieves a fixed value:

```
int *tmpPtr = toInvert[3]; 
printf( "*(TPointer + %d) : %d\n\n", 3, *(toInvert[3] + 1)); //Still gives the recently added value
```

What happens is when I try to print the values, only the last added values in the `setter` loop gets printed. Even if I change tmpPtr to `toInvert[1]`, it will still get the last set values.

But if I run the same code within the written for loop, it works as expected.

I need to know how to retrieve all the values that have been set. Thanks

**EDIT**
What I want is an array of 8 elements that contain 8 pointers. Each pointer in turn points to an array of 3 plain integers.
The array that I want should be like `[p1][p2]...[p8]` where `[p1]` points to an array of ints.

Comment: Ah, an array of pointers.  Such a simple concept, yet so complex in C.

Comment: I get 15,966 results when searching SE for "[c] array of pointers". (Im trying to suggest maybe your question has already been answered somewhere).

Comment: Why are you taking the address of the interplated variable?

Comment: You're storing the address of a local variable that ceases to exist when the loop body ends.

Comment: It's not even an array of pointers, it's an array of pointers-to-pointers!

Comment: Just as a tip, when you say int V[8]. The compiler allocates (in the stack, not in the heap if I'm not mistaken) 8 * sizeof(int) bytes, then it returns the pointer to the first element in that array and stores it in V. So V is just a pointer, not actually the array. When you say int foo= V[4] what it does is int foo= *(V+sizeof(int)*4)

Comment: now replace `int *tmpPtr = *toInvert[3]` for `int *tmpPtr = toInvert[3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared an array of pointers to pointers to ints here:

```
static int  **toInvert[8];
```

Remove a `*` to get an array of pointersto ints instead. Then assign `intrplated` instead of `&intrplated` on each iteration. `intrplated` is already a pointer, so `&intrplated` is a pointer to a pointer. All put together:

```
static int *toInvert[8];
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    int *intrplated = //Function call that returns int*
    toInvert[i] = intrplated;
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code based on your answer and it still gives the same issue - not retrieving any values except the last ones

Comment: @GauravWadhwani Can you be sure that the function you are calling is allocating new memory for each call? It could be reusing the same memory each time you call it in which case you would need to allocate your own memory on every iteration and `memcpy` the values into the memory you allocated.

Comment: You mean the function call that returns int*. There's no memory specific code there and that MAY be the issue. So how do I call that function using `memcpy`?

Comment: @GauravWadhwani If that function has no calls to `malloc` that is almost certainly the problem. I'll update my answer. One question first though, does that function return a pointer to a local variable (array declared in the function like `int local[3];`)? Using that pointer would be undefined behaviour in `C`, because the array doesn't exist after the function returns, in which case the function itself needs to be fixed, not the calling code.

Comment: The function has a declaration like static int  r[4]; and then after its operations, it returns r..

Comment: @GauravWadhwani That would be the problem then. Either you need to copy the data from the static array to your own space, or your function should allocate memory instead: `int *r = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);`. However then you'll also need to remember to write a `free` for each call to that function, otherwise you'll leak memory.

Comment: You've fixed it. That indeed was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to implement is an Array of Pointers, right?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LIMIT 3

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    static int  *toInvert[LIMIT];
    int *intrplated;
    for (i=0; i<LIMIT; i++)
    {
        intrplated = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
        intrplated[0] = rand();
        intrplated[1] = rand();
        intrplated[2] = rand();
        intrplated[3] = rand();
        intrplated[4] = rand();
        toInvert[i] = intrplated;
    }
    for (i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
    {
        printf("Tpointer to toInvert[%d] contains::\t [",i);
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",toInvert[i][j]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }

    putchar('\n');
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",toInvert[1][j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for(i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
    {
        free(toInvert[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on GCC 4.8.0

EDIT: See the change, the array of pointers retains the info

Output:

```
Tpointer to toInvert[0] contains::       [41 18467 6334 26500 19169 ]
Tpointer to toInvert[1] contains::       [15724 11478 29358 26962 24464 ] 
Tpointer to toInvert[2] contains::       [5705 28145 23281 16827 9961 ]

15724 11478 29358 26962 24464
```

Comment: While the code you've written works, it still results in the same issue that I am facing,i.e., only the last set values are retrieved. For example, if I print toInvert[1][2] , it will end up printing toInvert[LIMIT][2]....coz they were the ones that were set in the end

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
static int  *toInvert[8];
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
          int *intrplated = //Function call that returns int*
          toInvert[i] = intrplated;
          //printf("OL Value = %d\n\n\n\n\n",oLoop);
}
```

In your code, this

```
    static int  **toInvert[8];
```

means that you have a array of pointers to pointers.

This:

```
          int *intrplated = //Function call that returns int*
          toInvert[i] = intrplated;
```

is wrong. You are passing the address of the local variable `intrplated` to your array of pointer.

And this

```
int *tmpPtr = *toInvert[3];
printf( "*(TPointer + %d) : %d\n\n", 3, *(tmpPtr + 1));
```

is also wrong, it may work in your case because of the wrong declaration of `toInvert` , but is wrong. Look for more information about mixed pointers and array declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many `*`s throughout.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    static int  *toInvert[8];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
              int *intrplated = (int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));
              toInvert[i] = intrplated;
              //printf("OL Value = %d\n\n\n\n\n",oLoop);
    }

    int *tmpPtr = toInvert[3];
    printf( "*(TPointer + %d) : %d\n\n", 3, *(tmpPtr + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

This is an array of ints:

```
int x[8];
```

This is an array of *pointers to* int:

```
int *x[8];
```

Answer (score -1):

This code:

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    toInvert[i] = &intrplated;
}
```

is setting every element of `toInvert` to the address of `intrplated`. No matter which element of `toInvert` you look at you will dereference the same address and see whatever value is stored in `intrplated`.

Also, once the `for` loop exits, `intrplated` no longer exists so you will get undefined behavior when derferencing the values in the array.

This is what you would need if you want to store the pointers returned by the function.

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    toInvert[i] = intrplated;
}
```

If you are storing `int *` you need an array of `int *` such as:

```
int * toInvert[8];
```

Comment: I'm sure I need an array of Pointers.

Comment: "Array of Pointers" or "Array of Array of Pointers" ?

Answer (score -1):

Your function calls probably overwrites the pointer it returns. It should allocate this pointer using malloc and you should free it after you've used it.

You should also omit the & if the function returns a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the & in:

```
toInvert[i] = &intrplated;
```

the right way is:

```
toInvert[i] = &intrplated;
```

Since intrplated is already a pointer to an integer you are taking the address of the pointer not the pointer itself (essentially a pointer to a pointer).

Remember pointers are more like integers that the compiler treats as a position of memory so them themselves are also stored somewhere and have their own address too.

Also this:

```
static int  **toInvert[8];
```

Is not a pointer of pointers, it's a pointer to an array of pointers. I believe what you actually want is this:

```
static int  *toInvert[8];
```